# Attach image to notification given image URL

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification

I want to attach an image to my local notifications given an image URL. This is the extension to create an attachment:

```
import UserNotifications

extension UNNotificationAttachment {
    static func create(identifier: String, image: UIImage, options: [NSObject : AnyObject]?) -> UNNotificationAttachment? {
        let fileManager = FileManager.default
        let tmpSubFolderName = ProcessInfo.processInfo.globallyUniqueString
        let tmpSubFolderURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory()).appendingPathComponent(tmpSubFolderName, isDirectory: true)
        do {
            try fileManager.createDirectory(at: tmpSubFolderURL, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
            let imageFileIdentifier = identifier+".png"
            let fileURL = tmpSubFolderURL.appendingPathComponent(imageFileIdentifier)
            guard let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) else {
                return nil
            }
            try imageData.write(to: fileURL)
            let imageAttachment = try UNNotificationAttachment.init(identifier: imageFileIdentifier, url: fileURL, options: options)
            return imageAttachment        } catch {
                print("error " + error.localizedDescription)
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

When I schedule a new notification, I use it like this:

```
// url of the image such as http://www.unsplash.com/image.png
let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) 
guard let myImage = UIImage(data: data!) else { return }

if let attachment = UNNotificationAttachment.create(identifier: key, image: myImage, options: nil) {
    content.attachments = [attachment]
}
```

[image]

Creating a notification like this freezes the application for a few seconds because the app downloads the image synchronously. I have also tried to use `DispatchQueue` but it didn't change anything. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code downloads an image, parses it to create a UIImage, converts the image back to a block of PNG data, then writes this data to a temporary file.

You can skip the step where you create the `UIImage` and convert it back to a file.

Try using `URLSession` and `URLDataTask`:

```
let fileURL = ...
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, _, _) in
    do {
        try imageData.write(to: fileURL)
        let attachment = UNNotificationAttachment.create(identifier: key, image: myImage, options: nil)
        // call closure to call back with attachment and/or error
    }
    catch let ex {
        // call closure with error
    }
}
task.resume()
```

I've left out some error handling and other details, but this should give you the general idea of what's required to do it asynchronously. `URLSession`s use GCD to perform asynchronous networking.

Answer (score -1):

Download the image asynchronously using Alamofire then try to show it.

```
let destination: DownloadRequest.DownloadFileDestination = {
    _, _ in
    var documentsURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
    documentsURL.appendPathComponent("image.jpg")
    return (documentsURL, [.removePreviousFile, .createIntermediateDirectories])
}
Alamofire.download(url, to: destination).response {
    response in
    // do whatever you want with your image, for example if it is an audio file:
    do {
        self.player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(string: "\(response.destinationURL!)")!)
        self.player.volume = 1.0
        self.player.play()
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }        
}
```